# Combine two or more PDF ObjectStreams into single Stream using ABCPDF 9

Tags: pdf, abcpdf

I am try to find a way to write a function that you pass a param array of a number of object ids (at least two) and it combines the objects into a single stream and returns the id of the new stream object.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Function CombineToStream(ParamArray objects As Integer()) As Integer
    Dim stream = New StreamObject(myDoc.ObjectSoup)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim soType As Type = GetType(StreamObject)

    If objects.Length < 2 Then
      Return objects.FirstOrDefault()
    End If

    For index As Integer = 0 To objects.Length - 1
      Dim objectId As Integer = objects(index)

      Dim obj = myDoc.ObjectSoup.Item(objectId)

      Dim objType As Type = obj.GetType


      If objType = soType OrElse objType.IsSubclassOf(soType) Then

        Dim typedObj As StreamObject = TryCast(obj, StreamObject)

        If typedObj.Compressed Then
          typedObj.Decompress()
        End If

        Dim data As Byte() = typedObj.GetData()
        sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data))
      End If
    Next

    stream.SetData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()))

    For index As Integer = 0 To objects.Length - 1
      Dim objectId As Integer = objects(index)

      myDoc.Delete(objectId)
    Next

    Return stream.ID
  End Function
```

The function currently doesn't work as the objects passed in no longer appear in the document. I have a feeling it is something to do with either how the streams are being concatenated together or perhaps the new stream is not referenced anywhere in the document so is being removed when the pdf is saved ("abandoned" or unreferenced objects are deleted).

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You are probably correct. Just adding a brand new object to the soup won't make any page reference that object. You'll probably need to modify the object that was actually referencing one of the incoming streams, so it references the new stream.

Comment: Since a stream might be anything -- an image, a font, an RDF block -- I don't think there will be a standard way to find out what referenced the stream. I think your function as designed is too generic. You'll need a more tightly coupled function (or group of functions) that in addition to the streams to be combined, takes a parameter pointing to the "parent" stream which referenced the first stream, so it can be edited. And your function will need to expect a particular format of that parent stream, so it knows how to change the reference so it points to the new object.